# Why is the perpendicular got by means $\frac{dr}{rd\theta}\to -\frac{rd\theta}{dr}$ in polar form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

At the current moment I'm reading a textbook, George F. Simmons' **"Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes"**, and at first I had exactly the same question as was described here: [Orthogonal Trajectories Using Polar Coordinates. Correct Calculations, Two Different Answers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180929/orthogonal-trajectories-using-polar-coordinates-correct-calculations-two-diffe)

While that answer cleared some of my queries, this question bothers me;

In polar coordinates, why is the perpendicular is evaluated through: $\displaystyle{\frac{dr}{rd\theta}\to -\frac{rd\theta}{dr}}$ instead of $\displaystyle{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\to -\frac{d\theta}{dr}}$.

In my perspective, the differential equation of the family of original curves (in Cartesian coordinates) looks in the following manner:

If $\text{ }\displaystyle{\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x,y)}$, then the differential equation for the orthogonal trajectory of this family would

be, $\displaystyle{-\frac{dx}{dy} = f(x,y)}.$

Doing some research on my query, I found [that answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2180939/1143294).
However, I did not understand the explanation.

I would really appreciate it if someone could explain the post in a more detailed way.

Comment: Please use MathJax to improve readability.

Comment: The explanation you pointed to is already quite explicit. If what you want is more details to help you understand the explanation, you should give us more details about where the explanation fell short for you. I could, for example, give you an intuitive reason why finding the orthogonal curves is not just a matter of $\frac{dr}{d\theta}\to -\frac{d\theta}{dr}$, but that would be **less** detailed than what you've already pointed us to.

Answer (score 2):

At some point $M(\theta_0)$ of a curve $\mathcal C$ given in polar coordinates by $r(\theta),$ the angle $V=(\overrightarrow{OM(\theta_0)},\overrightarrow{M'(\theta_0)})$ between the radial vector and the tangent is given by
$$\tan V=\frac{r'(\theta_0)}{r(\theta_0)}.$$

Let $\rho(\theta)$ be a parametrization of some curve $\theta\mapsto N(\theta)$ normal to $\mathcal C$ at the same point, $N(\theta_0)=M(\theta_0).$ Similarly, the angle  $W=(\overrightarrow{ON(\theta_0)},\overrightarrow{N'(\theta_0)})$ is given by
$$\tan W=\frac{\rho'(\theta_0)}{\rho(\theta_0)}.$$

Now,$$W\equiv V+\frac\pi2\bmod\pi\implies\tan W=-\frac1{\tan V}\implies\frac{\rho'(\theta_0)}{\rho(\theta_0)}=-\frac{r(\theta_0)}{r'(\theta_0)}.$$